# How to make useEffect wait for redux dispatch execution before exucuting the function at next run?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm running this code inside useEffect hook:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    if (postStatus !== 'loading') {
      if (availableData.includes(pageNo)) {
      } else {
        dispatch(pageDataAdded(pageNo));
        dispatch(fetchPosts(pageNo));
      }
    }
  }, [pageNo, dispatch]);
```

#### What I expect:

On the first load, pageNo should be added to the list I maintain in the state  store. And then, `dispatch(fetchPosts(pageNo))` should be called.

On the second load, when pageNo doesn't change, `availableData.includes(pageNo)` condition should be satisfied, and `dispatch(fetchPosts(pageNo))` shouldn't be called.

#### What is actually happening:

`availableData.includes(pageNo)` runs twice with same `pageNo`, possibly because `dispatch(pageDataAdded(pageNo))` couldn't update the global state before the next run.

I'm using redux for loading paginated API. I want to update the store only when new pages are requested. I made this logic to do so.

What am I missing?